kubernetes node/cluster installations error
i hav ebeen having this error, when i want to create a new cluster or control plane on my serversince i uninstall kubernetes [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env" [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" [kubelet-check] Waiting for a healthy kubelet at http://127.0.0.1:10248/healthz. This can take up to 4m0s [kubelet-check] The kubelet is healthy after 501.787109ms [api-check] Waiting for a healthy API server. This can take up to 4m0s [api-check] The API server is not healthy after 4m0.000334534s Unfortunately, an error has occurred: context deadline exceeded This error is likely caused by: - The kubelet is not running - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled) If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands: - 'systemctl status kubelet' - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet' Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime. To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI. Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl: - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause' Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with: - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID' error execution phase wait-control-plane: could not initialize a Kubernetes cluster To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
